# Can I remove some topics from a BERTopic model?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I trained a BERTopic model and analysed the resulting topics. About half of them are good, but the others I don't need. Can I remove them from the model, to get faster predictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and I asked in github discussions for the package. If you ask there the package author answers very quickly.

Here is his answer to our question:

"Deleting topics is unlikely to help with speeding up the model in .transform as it is not possible to do that easily in the underlying models. Instead, I would either advise using the slower model and use .merge_topics to merge all unwanted topics into a single topic, so that it is easier to identify those. Or you can adjust the min_topic_size a bit lower to get a balance between helpful topics and speed of the transform function.

Do note that the transform function can be speed up by a number of different ways. For example, if you have an older GPU then embedding the documents can be much slower. In practice, it is helpful to identify which steps of the algorithm are relatively slow for you. By setting verbose=True, you have some indication of the time spent at each of those steps. If UMAP is too slow for you, then you can consider using PCA instead." -c Maarten Grootendorst

Also note that you could improve the speed of .transform by enabling the gpu acceleration for the latter two stages (by default only the first stage is gpu accelerated). You will find the info on that here https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/tips_and_tricks/tips_and_tricks.html#gpu-acceleration